# How could I view SAP B1 9.3 tables and views relationship diagram?

Tags: sql-server, sapb1

My SAP Business One 9.3 is MS SQL Server based.

1. What are the numbers of tables, views and triggers in SAP Business One version 9.3?
2. What is the meaning of those table groups?

   I found that those tables are categorized into groups with the four-lettered code-name, but have no description in details for each table.
3. How could I have those tables and views relationship diagram?

   I am unable to make that diagram visible with MS SQL Server.

I tried to find information on (1) and (3) in MS SQL Server 2016 (support with SAP Business One 9.3), but I am unable to make that diagram visible with MS SQL Server. Why and how do I do that?

For information on (2), I tried to explore the table's properties (fields, data types, primary keys, indexed, etc.) at: https://sap.erpref.com, but have no detailed description of the table use.

Answer (score 1):

SAP Business One is software that uses, in your case, a SQL Server database. I think what you are asking is what is the make up of that database? You may just be confused about software vs database but it also seems you want to know more about the limits of SQL Server.

Based on what I'm reading,

1. Out of the box, there are [2546 tables](https://sap.erpref.com/?schema=BusinessOne9.3) inside of Business One 9.3. I haven't found anything that speaks of views and triggers. I'm sure it has many of both but I don't know exact numbers.
2. I think the table groups you're seeing are OITM, OCRD, OINV, ORDR, and INV1. Those are not table groups. They're tables. You can find them in the list in the link above. Also in that link, you can see the tables are broken up into 12 groups (Administration, Banking, Business Partners, etc...).
3. As far as a relational diagram that will map out all 2546 tables for you, I didn't find that and I doubt it exists. Learning how a database is designed and how all of the objects relate to each other takes time and effort. You're going to have invest time to work with the database to understand how it all works together. Either that or you will have to find someone to teach it to you.

As for SQL Server, it doesn't have a hard limit on how many tables you can have but it does have a limit on objects. If you add up all of the database objects (tables, views, stored procedures, triggers, etc...) SQL Server can not exceed [2,147,483,647 objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).